# Detect multiple devices on network using UDP broadcast - C#

Tags: c#, networking, udp

I am aware that there a plenty of questions on UDP broadcast for detecting network devices but none of the answers really work for me. I'm guessing that I'm missing something and would be grateful for any help.

I have designed a system which sits on a network and runs a UDP server. Upon receiving a message on some port (AP) it will send a reply back to the sending IP/port.

On the C# side I use the following code:

```
UdpClient Client = new UdpClient();
                var RequestData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Discover");
                var ServerEp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
                byte[] ServerResponseData = { 0 };

                Client.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReceiveTimeout, 1000);

                Client.EnableBroadcast = true;
                Client.Send(RequestData, RequestData.Length, new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, AnnouncePort));

                ServerResponseData = LanguageUtils.IgnoreErrors(() => Client.Receive(ref ServerEp));

                if (ServerResponseData != null)
                {
                    var ServerResponse = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ServerResponseData);

                    deviceList.Add(ServerEp.Address.ToString());

                    QueryFoundDevices(deviceList);
                    AvailableDevicesList.Nodes[0].Expand();
                }
```

My issue is that I can only ever detect one of my devices at a time. Ideally, I would like to be able to receive messages from an unlimited number of devices.

I have also tried using async methods, in which case I just receive my own message and don't see any devices. Code example of that:

```
static void OnUdpData(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            // this is what had been passed into BeginReceive as the second parameter:
            UdpClient socket = result.AsyncState as UdpClient;
            // points towards whoever had sent the message:
            IPEndPoint source = new IPEndPoint(0, 0);
            // get the actual message and fill out the source:
            byte[] message = socket.EndReceive(result, ref source);
            // do what you'd like with `message` here:
            Console.WriteLine("Got " + message.Length + " bytes from " + source);
            // schedule the next receive operation once reading is done:
            socket.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(OnUdpData), socket);
        }
```

Can anyone please advise how I can do this?

**Update:**
Based on comments - these are Ethernet based devices and I have verified that both devices are replying using Wireshark.

Comment: `LanguageUtils.IgnoreErrors(() => Client.Receive(ref ServerEp));` This is not clear: LanguageUtils in combination with Client.Receive (strange combi).. Can you give some details?

Comment: I think at the time I wrote this I was having some issues so was trying to suppress errors. It's not required and will work at just ServerResponseData = Client.Receive(ref ServerEp);

Comment: What went wrong with the async version?

Comment: The async version works in the sense that I get a reply from a single device, but only a single device. If I have two devices on the network I only see one of them. If I keep sending broadcasts, the device I see occasionally changes so I know they are both working.

Comment: Are you aware of losing packets on wifi?

Comment: These are all Ethernet only devices right now. I didn't think to mention that in the question.

Comment: You have to share complete sample project somewhere. The code snippet above shows that you only handle the first response, so meet the symptom above. You have to handle all responses.

Comment: Yes, I understand why the first section of code would only get one response. I tried the second piece in an effort to resolve this but it does not improve things. With regards to device discovery, there isn't much more to show. The first section just shows that I add any responses to a list. I then query these devices to get more info. If the second section of code had worked I would have done something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where is is correct to do this but I have now worked out a way of doing this based upon Lex Li's comment. I thought I would share this just in case anyone else is having a similar issue.

```
                UdpClient Client = new UdpClient();
                var RequestData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Discover");
                var ServerEp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
                byte[] ServerResponseData = { 0 };

                Client.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReceiveTimeout, 1000);

                Client.EnableBroadcast = true;
                Client.Send(RequestData, RequestData.Length, new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, AnnouncePort));

                ServerResponseData = LanguageUtils.IgnoreErrors(() => Client.Receive(ref ServerEp));
                string ServerResponse;
                while (ServerResponseData != null)
                {
                    ServerResponse = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ServerResponseData);

                    deviceList.Add(ServerEp.Address.ToString());

                    QueryFoundDevices(deviceList);
                    AvailableDevicesList.Nodes[0].Expand();

                    ServerResponseData = LanguageUtils.IgnoreErrors(() =>Client.Receive(ref ServerEp))
                }
```

Lex Li pointed out that the first code section I posted in my answer would only receive the first reply. I tried to read the next response and it worked. I am now using the above, which likely needs further optimisation but is working well so far.

Thanks for the help folks!

Comment: For the last 20 years, you should not use broadcast. IPv6 does not even have broadcast, so your application could not be ported to IPv6. The way to do this is with multicast.

Comment: Thanks, Ron. I was not aware of this - I will look in to multicast immediately.